# how to get the object posted by datables ajax loading process

Tags: jquery, datatables

i know the initialisation of `datatables` with

```
jqTable = $('#ttest').dataTable({        
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/Api/GetData",
        method: "POST",
        data: function (d) {
            d.MoreForSearch = new Array();
        }
    }
});
```

what i would like is:

```
jqTable = $('#ttest').dataTable({
    buttons: [{
            text: 'custom',
            className: 'btn btn-default btn-xs',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                //some ajax with data posted by datatables <<============
                alert('go go custom');
            }}],
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/Api/GetData",
        method: "POST",
        data: function (d) {
            d.MoreForSearch = new Array();
        }
    }
});
```

I can't find in the api how to get the posted data ?

By *posted data* I mean the object provided as `d` to the *function* used as data parameter for the ajax call.

Comment: what do you means about get posted data? did you mean last json which will build to table?

Comment: @plonknimbuzz I try to edit my question

Comment: Still a bit unclear, do you want to *add* something to the *request* or somehow access the *response* from the server?

Comment: @lofihelsinki I want to emit a request with the same payload as the one emited by datatables when querying data from the server.

Comment: Could you save your custom reuqest vars to a global and then read those in `data: function (d) {`and append to to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to send your same data to another ajax when you click your button

```
...
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
    var json = this.ajax.json();//last response
    console.log( json); 
    var data = this.ajax.params();//the request
    data.MoreForSearch = ['a','b','c']; //you can modify request
    console.log( data); 
    $.ajax({//send to ajax
        url: 'bb.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(d){
            console.log(d);
        }
    })
}
...
```

here the reference about this to help you next time:

- [get all data in the table](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData)
- [event when datatables initialised](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)
- [event when ajax/xhr happened](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr)
- [get last ajax data (json) loaded](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json())
- [get request parameter which will send to server](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params())

Comment: `ajax.params()` will do.